# Subdomain redirect problem

Tags: redirect, wpdb, wp-load.php

Wordpress is installed my root directory(/root/). I have a subdomain(dammani.techbrij.com) and I want to access some files of main domain from sub domain.
I have done following thing:

```
include_once('/root/wp-config.php');
include_once('/root/wp-load.php');
include_once('/root/wp-includes/wp-db.php');
```

Now, "http://techbrij.com/dammani" is working fine, but "http://dammani.techbrij.com" not working. It redirects to main domain.

If i give any wrong path in include_once, I'm getting error without redirect.
Let me know how to fix this issue.

Edit: I'm using same database for my app. So i want to use same wpdb functionality for subdomain.

Comment: It would be helpful to explain why you're including those files so anyone answering is in a better position to advise you on alternative methods. It may even serve as a better question to ask **"How do i X"** (whatever you're attempting to do) rather than **"I did X and it caused Y, how do i fix it"**...

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure if that is cause of your issue, but you do not load WordPress in correct way.

Please see [Integrating WordPress with Your Website](http://codex.wordpress.org/Integrating_WordPress_with_Your_Website) in Codex for details.